# I get the error: "Latex error: File not found. " eventhough the file is .png and it is in the correct folder

Tags: graphics

[image: beginning of my file]

I want to include a `.png` file that is called `Screenshot 1` and is in folder `Screenshotsforassignment`, but typing `\includegraphics{Screenshot 1}` gives me the error:

```
LaTex Error: File 'Screenshot 1' not found.
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Edit: I solved it!

Comment: dont use spaces in filenames

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! A [minimal working exapmle](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

David Carlisle almost certainly identified the problem: Do not use spaces in file names. Also avoid underscore, because it is a special character in TeX.

Sometimes you can deal with this by escaping the offending space (or underscore). But even when that works, it is something you are likely to forget, then the problem will re-appear and you won't remember why.

So, change the image file name to `Screenshot-1.png` and also remember that the names are case-sensitive.

EDIT: This may also happen if there are spaces (or underscores) in the folder structure leading to the image. Also, if you use absolute paths on Windows, be sure that use use C://folder/subfolder rather than C:\folder\subfolder.

If you already have a folder structure and/or file names with spaces or underscores, and you do not wish to change the names, you can try escaping the characters like this:

```
folder\ name\ with\ spaces/folder\_name\_with\_underscores
```

Also see if that is done in your `graphicspath`.

If you do a lot of screenshots, perhaps you can change your operating system settings, so that the file name is saved without space or underscore.

Comment: I tried changing the name but I'm still getting the same error, do you know what else might be causing the error? Do you think the error might be in the \graphicspath line? [this](http://prntscr.com/hopob9) is where the file is stored.

Comment: @MathijsMoonen See my edited answer. If that still does not help, then I do not know more. I looked at your images.